# pandas read_excel function prints one sheet_name strangely

Tags: python, excel, pandas

it is very strange that when I use the read_excel to the file I uploaded.
It will print out the sheet_name of the second sheet name. But there is nothing in the second sheet. Anyone knows the reason? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: file link below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y7spQJMwvtGoqQCkEnvWQTnHVOvf545D/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=108781473800350304938&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason, sharing with you.
If you have a reference in the Formula- Name Manager with naming "Print_Titles", when the read_excel called, it will print out the name of the sheet.[image]